# What is cross validation rate in grid.py indicate?

Tags: libsvm

I know what cross validation and what grid.py is does.

I know that parameter g and g are supposed to be used while training but I have no idea what is this third parameter rate?

I get cross-validation rate as 95.32 % . What does this signify ?? 
Is it good or bad ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cross-validation rate is the percentage of samples that has been correctly classified during the cross-validation step (with the best `c` and `g` parameters found), so having a 95% success is a great result. Parameters of `grid.py` are the following:

- `-log2c`: `c` regularization parameter
- `-log2g`: set gamma in kernel function `exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)`
- `-v n`: `n`-fold cross validation
- `-svmtrain pathname`: set svm executable path and name
- `-gnuplot pathname`: set gnuplot executable path and name
- `-out pathname`: set output file path and name
- `-png pathname`: set graphic output file path and name (default `dataset.png`)